# Android back button doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, android-activity

When I click on back button from third activity it goes the first activity but I don't know what is wrong, help please. Thanks in advance

This is my Manifest file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="@android:icon">
    <activity
        android:name=".firstActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:name=".secondActivity"
        android:label="Todo List"
        android:parentActivityName=".firstActivy"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.akbari.test.Main" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:name=".thirdActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_client_list"
        android:parentActivityName=".secondActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.akbari.test.Main" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

I used this in my second activity and I think the problem with System.exit(0)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
       appSettings();
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_refresh){
        init();
    } else if (id == R.id.action_exit){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are finishing the second activity when the third one starts

Comment: you must have finished second activity and not finished first one

Comment: post your java code too for calling second and third activity

Comment: show your activities & call `super.onBackPressed();`

Comment: System.exit() will only finish your app when you click the exit menu item. But in your case, you are clicking the back button. Post relevant codes of your second and third activities here

Answer (score 0):

If you are using upper version than `4.0` (API level 16), then obviously the reason may be you have finished your Second Activity as comments.

If you are using lower than `4.0` then it's happening because of your `meta-data` where `android:value` of Second and Third Activity points to the same.

Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) how meta-data is provided, and see the `android:value` attribute which is as same to the value of `android:parentActivityName`

```
android:value="yourPackage.yourParentActivity"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your order of Activities in Manifest file for example which comes first when app launches

```html
<activity
            
            (e.g the home screen which has buttons on it when we launch the app it comes first so it is on the top)
            android:name=".firstActivity"


            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        (e.g these are buttons which is in the home screen  )
        <activity android:name=".Second Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

Comment: Also check your onPause method if whether you used   Intent a=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class); if there is remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with `android:noHistory="true"`, I removed that now it works.